# How to reduce memory footprint when instantiating a hierarchy of model objects in Cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, lazy-loading, cocoa-design-patterns

I'm writing a quiz application for iPhone using basic `NSObject` subclasses to represent the models.  At runtime the various controllers instantiate the model classes and populate them with data read in from a plist on the disk.

The model classes represent the basic hierarchy of a multiple choice quiz:

- One application has many quizzes
- One quiz has many questions
- One question has many answers

Currently, when the `QuizController` class loads its `Quiz` object, it populates its `questions` `NSArray` property with `Question` instances, and as each of those `Question` instances are initialized, they each initialize their own `NSArray`s of `Answer` instances.

I recognize that I don't need every question in memory when I load a quiz, I only need a question at a certain index in the `Quiz` instance's `questions` array.

I'm thinking that some sort of dataSource protocol or lazy loading pattern would help reduce the memory footprint incurred when loading up any particular quiz on this system, but I'm unsure how to implement either.  I'd really appreciate any suggestions that the community had in terms of:

What pattern would be appropriate to use here?  A short code snippet would also be hugely helpful for me to understand how I might begin to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am all for proper design to minimize memory usage, but you also have to be pragmatic sometimes.

You will have at least 20 MB of memory available for your app on older devices, so I am actually not sure if it makes sense to spend a lot of time on lazy loading questions.

You can probably easily load hundreds of questions in memory without ever noticing it.

My advice: start the non-lazy way. Look with Instruments at the memory usage. It it is aceptable then leave it. If you are pushing the limits then invest time in optimizing.

Comment: I agree with you that in practice this is what I should do and I am in fact doing this.  I'm just curious about best practices, as I am a relatively inexperienced programmer working alone for the most part.

Comment: Well, one very good practice would be to store all your data in Core Data, which can load data on demand.

However, without knowing numbers this might not be true.

For example, Core Data has a certain overhead and base memory usage. It may well be that your quizz data fits in there completely.

Do you know how much memory or disk space your quizz data will use?